# Swagger validation somehow throws No API path found that matches request exception

Tags: java, validation, kotlin, swagger, openapi

I have request: `http://127.0.0.1:8088/api/calendar/events?from=2020-06-29T00:00:00Z&to=2020-08-10T00:00:00Z`

I have in openapi.yaml:

```
paths:
  /api/calendar/events:
    get:
      summary: Returns events in given time range
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: from
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
          allowReserved: true
        - in: query
          name: to
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
          allowReserved: true
      responses:
        # TODO: Describe response?
        '200':
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: object
                  additionalProperties: true
        '401':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/UnauthorizedError'
        '5XX':
          $ref: '#/components/responses/UnexpectedError'
```

But it throws exception:

```
[ERROR][GET /api/calendar/events?from=2020-06-29T00:00:00Z&to=2020-08-10T00:00:00Z] No API path found that matches request '/api/calendar/events?from=2020-06-29T00:00:00Z&to=2020-08-10T00:00:00Z'.
```

I am using **com.atlassian.oai:swagger-request-validator-core:2.10.0** (or 2.8.0 – all the same). Everything else in api works fine, but on some ran dom paths I have errors like this.

Please, help. Thank you!

Comment: Can you see if the '5XX': is the problem and change that to 500? Some tooling thinks that its always going to be a numeric string, but this half the reason _why_ it's a string.

Comment: Everywhere else I have one of responses like this. "5XX". Everything else works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I to describe path as: `/api/calendar/events?from={}&to={}`